# Python web-scraping, problems

Tags: python-3.x, web

Here is a small segment of my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def mancity():
    manclist = []
    f = 'mancity.txt'
    fo = open(f, 'w')
    root_url = "http://www.whoscored.com"
    index_url = root_url + "/Teams/167"
    r = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    playstyle = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "character-card singular"})
    for item in playstyle:
        chellist.append(item.text)
    mstr = ''.join(map(str, manclist))
    fo.write(mstr)
    print(mstr)
```

The idea of the code is to scrape a website and extract the data to a text file.
Now the code DOES work however not consistently. Sometimes it works, sometimes it returns no values at all.
I am at a loss as to why this is? is it because my request is being denied?
It's rather annoying as when nothing is returned the text file is overwritten by blank space.

Please run the code your self, and see your outputs.
(this is for educational purposes)

Answer (score 0):

When using requests, you can check the `status_code` attribute of the resulting object. It should be between 200 and 299 for succesful requests.
When it's the case, `r.content` can contain some explanation of the error.

Comment: I used these commands you mentioned, when the program does not display an output. the status code is == 200, and the content is b"". When the program does provide an output, the status code is still 200, however the content contains the entire HTML of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another similar program scraping a different website and it works flawlessly. I guess the factor is that this website is somehow denying my requests.